# Low Level MouseHook not working depending where SetWindowsHookEx is being called

Tags: c, winapi, hook

I'm writing a dll in which a function is used to call :

```
mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
WH_MOUSE_LL,
MouseHookProc,
0,  // tried too with (HINSTANCE) inj_hModule, which is hModule from DllMain
0);
```

When I put this in DllMain, or in the dll's WndProc (the one working with the messages, for instance in case WM_CREATE: or whatever ), it is working OK.

But I need to put it in a separate function, so I can hook when I call it. When I do it, GetLastError says that it succeeded, but the hook isn't working, MouseHookProc is just never called (I put some trace in it to check).

I also tried with other hInstance values for the 3rd parameter, no success either...

Searching for a solution, I read that low level hooks must be set globally, I must confess that I'm not sure to fully understand that as I think it may be the problem, is some regular function not global and wndproc functions global ??? Not sure.

It is quite frustrating as it works ok when I call it at init, if I don't find a solution quickly maybe I'll dispatch some custom message so I can SetWindowsHookEx when I want but it will still be in the wndproc...

Thanks for helping me and Merry Christmas everyone !!!

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and try to be specific. Avoid terminology that doesn't make sense, like *"the dll's WndProc"*. Without any information to go by I would guess you didn't read the following from the documentation: *"The thread that installed the hook must have a message loop."*

Comment: Yes yes it has one (message loop). I would say callback function for the wndproc stuff, but it surely is a bigger mistake. I used to think wndproc would make sense as I explained it right after too. Does those have a name ??? Would like to know it if they do. I'm shortening my code to an SSCCE right now. Thanks llnspectable.